# Better way to handle this code

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, fluent-nhibernate

I am working on a MVC3 application with nhibernate and SQL server. Have written a normal method which is re-usable. Please find the below code and let me know a better way to handle it. I have observed to execute this piece of code it is taking a long time.

```
      private void GetParentCompany(IEnumerable<Company> companiesList)
          {
        foreach (var company in companiesList)
        {
            long? dunsUltimateParent = company.DUNSUltimateParent;
            Company ultimateParent = _companyService.GetCompanyByDUNS(Convert.ToInt64(dunsUltimateParent));
            if (ultimateParent != null)
            {
                company.UltimateParentName = ultimateParent.CompanyName;
                company.UltimateCompanyId = ultimateParent.CompanyId;
                company.UltimateParentDuns = ultimateParent.DUNS;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: could you not use a SQL join on the two tables to produce just one model (no need to do this method that way)

Comment: Deploy NHibernate Profiler: http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/nhprof and see where the bottleneck is.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an index to your company.DUNS column might help. However consider to introduce a many-to-one relationship from company to (parent) company.

Place a UltimateParent property with type company in the company class. The fields UltimateParentName and UltimateParentDuns would then be redundant and you could simply get company.UltimateParent.Name for example. The mapping of UltimateParent can be done using 'References' in fluent-nhibernate.

```
References(x => x.UltimateParent);
```

Comment: Could you please give me an idea with the code. Now I have public virtual Company UltimateParent {get;set;} . I am still not able to get how to write the mapping in CompanyMap. The unique id for this mapping is not the primary key of the table which is (CompanyId) but a different column which maps to column DUNS which is called DUNSUltimateParent.